# DDD - Value Object flavor of an Entity

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design

I've seen some DDD projects with value object representations of entities.
They usually appear like `EmployeeDetail`, `EmployeeDescriptor`, `EmployeeRecord`, etc. Sometimes it holds the entity ID, sometimes not.

**Is that a pattern? If yes, does it have a name?
What are the use cases?
Are they value objects, parameter objects, or anything else?
Are they referenced in the domain model (as property) or are they "floating" just as parameters and returns of methods?**

Going beyond...

I wonder if I can define any aggregate as an `ID + BODY (detail, descriptor, etc) + METHODS (behavior)`.

```java
public class Employee {
    private EmployeeID id;
    private EmployeeDetail detail; //the "body"
}
```

Could I design my aggregates like this to avoid code duplication when using this kind of object?

The immediate advantage of doing this is to avoid those methods with too many parameters in the aggregate factory method.

```java
public class Employee {
   ...
   public static Employee from(EmployeeID id, EmployeeDetail detail){...};
}
```

instead of

```java
public class Employee {
   ...
   public static Employee from(EmployeeID id, + 10 Value Objects here){...};
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Among other characteristics, value objects are meant to be _immutable_: whenever any of the value object property changes, you have to replace the entire value object instead of mutating it. This is the first limitation that comes to mind.

Answer (score 4):

What you're proposing is the idiomatic (via `case class`es) approach to modeling an aggregate in Scala: you have an ID essentially pointing to a mutable container of an immutable object graph representing the state (and likely some static functions for defining the state transitions).  You are moving away from the more traditional OOP conceptions of domain-driven design to the more FP conceptions (come to the dark side... ;) ).

If doing this, you'll typically want to partition the state so that operations on the aggregate will [as] rarely [as possible] change multiple branches of the state, which enables reuse of as much of the previous object graph as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. And what about the main question (bold in the text)? What are those objects? What are the use-cases?

Comment: Yes, this "mutable container" is not an entity nor a value object. I really don't know what are the consequences of having a "new" concept in my domain model.

Comment: I think the consequences would be the usual ones of moving from OOP to FP. The most important among them would be the _performance penalty_ if you don't use _functional data structures_ to model your domain.

Answer (score 1):

> Could I design my aggregates like this to avoid code duplication when using this kind of object?

What you are proposing is representing the entire entity except its id as a 'bulky' value object. A concept or object's place in your domain (finding that involves defining your *bounded contexts* and their *ubiquitous languages*) dictates whether it is treated as a value object or an entity, not coding convenience.

However, if you go with your scheme as a general principle, you risk *tangling unrelated data* into a single value object. That leads to many conceptual and technical difficulties. Take *updating an entity* for example. Entities are designed to evolve in their *lifecycle* in response to operations performed on it. Each operation updates only the *relevant properties* of an entity. With your solution, for any operations, you have to *construct a new value object* (as value objects are defined to be *immutable*) as replacement, potentially copying many irrelevant data.

The examples you are citing are most likely entities with *only one value object attribute.*

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. And what about the main question (bold in the text)? What are those objects? What are the use-cases?

Answer (score 1):

OK - great question...

**DDD Question Answered**

The difference between an entity object and a value object comes down to perspective - and needs for the given situation.

Let's take a simple example...

A airplane flight to your favourite destination has...

1. Seats 1A, 10B, 21C available for you too book (entities)
2. 3 of 22 Seats available (value object).

The first reflects individually identifiable seat entities that could be filled.
The second reflects that there are 3 seats available (value object).

With value object you are not concerned with which individual entities (seats) are available - just the total number.

It's not difficult to understand that it depends on who's asking and how much it matters.

Some flights you book a seat and others you book a (any) seat on a plane.

**General**

Ask yourself a question! Do I care about the individual element or the totality?

NB. An entity (plane) can consider seats, identity and / or value object - depending on use case. Also worth noting, it has multiple depends - Cockpit seats are more likely to be entity seats; and passenger seats value objects.

I'm pretty sure I want the pilot seat to have a qualified pilot; and qualified co-pilot; but I don't really care that much where the passengers seats.  Well except I want to make sure the emergency exit seats are suitable passengers to help exit the plane in an emergency.

No simple answer, but a complex set of a pieces to thing about, and to consider for each situation and domain complexity.

Hope that explains some bits, happy to answer follow-up questions...

Comment: Thank you @mrdnk. I really understand that sometimes you need a VO flavor of an entity in other BC (it's very common), and even inside the same BC (in another aggregate - it's not so common). I think the suffix "descriptor" looks like a "pattern" much more than an attempt to express the ubiquitous language. We know we need to reference another AR by its ID. Now I wonder if the "descriptor" suffix is used when referencing by ID is not enough and you want to copy extra data to avoid roundtrip to the other aggregate repository. So you need to put it in a wrapper. How would you name it?